# Bash script to search csv file column and count how many times a value shows up

Tags: bash, csv, counter

I am really new a bash and I was trying to search a csv file column for a value and then add a counter. I found this online but it prints it and I have been trying to count how many times an `R` shows up and not print the whole thing.

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' $file
```

The csv file is like:

```
12345,R,N,N,Y,N,N,N,Bob Builder
```

I am looking for `R` in column 2. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

The following should do what you want (where file.csv is your csv file):

Case sensitive version:

```
cut -f 2 -d , file.csv | grep -c R
```

Case insensitive version:

```
cut -f 2 -d , file.csv | grep -ic R
```

**Explanation**

`cut -f 2 -d , file.csv`
This takes each line of `file.csv` and extracts the specified fields.  The `-f 2` option means extract field 2 and the `-d ,` means use a '`,`' as the field delimiter.  The output of this is then piped to `grep`.

`grep -c R` This looks for lines containing 'R'.  Since it is passed the contents of the previous `cut` command, it is looking for an 'R' in field two.  The `-c` option means count the number of matching lines.

Comment: thank you soo much .. this worked perfectly... could you possible explain how it works?

Comment: you should use grep -c instead of piping to wc -l :)

Comment: That made a lot of sense :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using awk only:

```
awk -F "\",\"" '{if ($2 == "R") cnt++} END{print cnt}' file
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding unnecessary piping multiple commands and doing it all in awk only.

Answer (score 1):

For a fun - perl only - this count everything.

```
perl -F, -anle 'map{$cnt{$_}{$F[$_]}++}0..$#F;END{print $cnt{1}{R}}'
```